# IE text shadow hack

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I've been using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for awhile to render CSS3 in IE, one of the downsides is it's lack of text shadow support which is apparently still in alpha stage so is there an htc file or jQuery plugin for text shadowing in ie that won't conflict with Pie?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [CSS3 support for Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)